# SurfaceView horrible performance

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, drawing, surfaceview

So I am basically creating a 2D physics engine I want to use for other projects in the future.
The only problem here is the performance of my Surface View.
I get a constant 60 logic-updates per second, but only 6 frames per second no matter what I do.
If I call the draw() method in my calculating thread, I get 6 fps.
If I create a whole new thread which is only drawing, without any delay in the loop

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            for (GameObject object : objects) {object.draw(canvas);}

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        gs.totalFrames++;
    }
}
```

(gs = Game Surface) I get 6 fps. The draw() function of my game object is pretty simple:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle((float) x, (float) y, 10, paint);
}
```

Why is the performance so bad? (I only have 5 game objects, so that's 5 circles, which should not be a performance problem at all!)
I also tried a runnable posting itself delayed, but that was bad, too.
Calling the draw() function in the GameSurface from the thread instead of doing the drawing directly in it, didn't change anything. A tiny delay didn't improve it either.

Do I somehow use the SurfaceView in a way it's not supposed to be used in?
What is the problem?

Comment: > "I get a constant 60 updates per second, but only 6 frames per second no matter what I do." What exactly does this mean?

Comment: @kujeensiti I mean that the game logic, the movement etc. is being calculated 60 times per second, but all that is only drawn to the surface 6 times per second